# Bug Found in SE chat's upload feature

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

There is a bug in chat's upload feature ,If you had previously posted an image using upload and you open up the dialouge again without selecting a pic and press cancel it reposts the previous image without conformation

Comment: This has also been reported on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94649/weird-repost-of-last-picture-in-chat

Comment: This is a browser bug in Chrome (unless you say you use a different browser -- but that would honestly surprise me). We'll look at adding a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

We have added a workaround for this Chrome (or possibly WebKit) bug; see [Weird repost of last picture in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94649/weird-repost-of-last-picture-in-chat/96562#96562).

Comment: Awesome! (PS: Its a global webkit bug)